# Objective C generics - Conditional compilation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, generics, c-preprocessor, xcode7

What's the easiest way to write code that takes advantage of generics when compiled with Xcode 7 but can also be compiled on Xcode 6?

I would guess that some sort of a preprocessor trick can do the job, maybe something like this:

```
#define XCODE7_ONLY(x) ...

NSDictionary XCODE7_ONLY(<NSString*, NSString*>)* dictionary;
```

Comment: I'm curious.. why would you want to do this? Soon you'll only be able to submit apps with Xcode 7.

Comment: I want to test that my app works on 10.9 by compiling it with Base SDK 10.9.

Comment: You might want to consider if this will really improve the code, it there a problem with incorrect objects being added to a dictionary? Not that the added type information is a bad thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `__has_feature(objc_generics)` macro to test for Obj-C generics. So you might want to try:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_generics)
#define XCODE7_ONLY(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define XCODE7_ONLY(...)
#endif
```